# openssl ocsp request serial

Tags: openssl, ocsp

Given this openssl ocsp request from [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ocsp.html)

```
openssl ocsp -index demoCA/index.txt -rsigner rcert.pem -CA demoCA/cacert.pem
 -issuer demoCA/cacert.pem -serial 1
```

what is the meaning of -serial parameter?

Answer (score 2):

As per https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt the OCSP request needs to contain the `serial number` of the certificate whose status is being checked. This can be provided to `openssl` using the `serial` option or using the `cert` option in which case the serial number is extracted from the certificate provided.